# Calculate hour between two times in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a problem to calculate hours between two times, suppose I have end time 11:00PM  and start time 10:00PM, now I want to get a result `1 hours`. here end time must be less than or equal current time. `I am using sql server 2012 express edition.` Any idea will help me lots.

My Query:

```
        SELECT     
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.id,
            VM_Event.EventName,
            VM_EventStage.RaceDetail,
            VM_EventStage.[Date],
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.EventStageID,    
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.StartTime,
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.EndTime, 
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.Location,
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.BriefingTime,
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.BriefingLocation,
            SET_Role.PositionTitle,
            DIFFERENCE(VM_EventStageRoleShift.EndTime,VM_EventStageRoleShift.StartTime) AS SystemLoggedHour --eg. 11:00PM - 10:00PM **(here is my problem)**
        FROM         
            VM_Event
            INNER JOIN VM_EventStage ON VM_EventStage.EventID = VM_Event.id 
            INNER JOIN VM_EventStageRole ON VM_EventStageRole.EventStageID = VM_EventStage.id 
            INNER JOIN VM_EventStageRoleDesc ON VM_EventStageRoleDesc.EventStageRoleID = VM_EventStageRole.id 
            INNER JOIN VM_EventStageRoleShift ON VM_EventStageRoleShift.EventStageRoleID = VM_EventStageRole.id 
            INNER JOIN SET_Role ON SET_Role.id = VM_EventStageRole.RoleID           
        WHERE
            --VM_EventStageRoleDesc.ManagerID = @ManagerID
            VM_EventStageRoleShift.[Status] <> 3
            AND VM_EventStage.[Date]  <= Convert(date, GETDATE())
            AND VM_EventStageRoleShift.EndTime <= --CurrentTime  **(here is my problem)**
```

**N.B: EndTime and StartTime both are nvarchar(8)**

Answer (score 0):

Accurate answer depend upon real sample data of starttime and endtime that is lying in your table.

you can try like this,

```
select datediff(hour,cast('10:00PM' as datetime)
,cast( '11:00PM' as datetime))
```

Comment: How can I set endtime less than or equal current time into where clause?

Comment: this part is not clear to me.give one example.what to do you mean by it ?

Answer (score -2):

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME('2009-05-18 11:45:42'), FROM_UNIXTIME('2009-05-20 15:16:39')) AS min_diff

Comment: Minus 1 because sql server does not have those functions.